# tsql select closest date set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to select a set of dates that is closest to (including before and after) a specific date.

I'm pretty close, all I want to do now is select the top 10 'Closeness' to 0... but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
BEGIN
Declare @DateCenter datetime2 = '2011-03-30 00:15:00'
Declare @DateStart datetime2 = DATEADD(day,-7,@DateCenter)
Declare @DateEnd datetime2 = DATEADD(day,7,@DateCenter)
SELECT TOP 30 *, DateDiff(hour, Utc, @DateCenter) as Closeness
FROM [CheckIns]
WHERE Utc BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd
END
```

Comment: Could you `ORDER BY` the closeness value?

Comment: The closeness values are both positive and negative. What I want is the numbers closest to 0... so if the values were (-3,-1,1,2,4,5) and I wanted the top 4 it would product (-3,-1,1,2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 or 30, you're narrative and code sample don't match. Anyhow, the following should work:

```
select top 10 *
from (
     select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(minute,Utc,@DateCenter))) as rn
     from CheckIns
) t
order by rn
```

this doesn't distinguish between those before and those after - it simply seeks the 10 closest. If you wanted, say, the 10 that precede a date, and the 10 that succeed it, then you'd need 2 orderings, or possibly a `PARTITION BY` clause also to the `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

If you wanted to include tied results, you'd need to switch to using `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: The 30 is not selecting the closest 30. It's a filter used to reduce the set. It's not quite right... The query I perceive as a inner query.

Comment: @Jonathon - hopefully you can see though, that the key is to use a window function, ordering by `ABS(DATEDIFF(...` so that the lower numbers are assigned to those whose date is closest to the provided date.

Comment: Will your query use an index on `Utc` or it will have to scan the whole table?

Comment: @ypercube - no, it's not indexable. obviously, whether that matters for the OP is unknown at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will use the (if there is one) index on `Utc` :

```
SELECT TOP 10
    *
FROM
(  SELECT TOP 10
        *
        , DateDiff(hour, Utc, @DateCenter) as Closeness
    FROM [CheckIns]
    WHERE Utc >= @DateCenter 
    ORDER BY Utc
UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 10
        *
        , DateDiff(hour, @DateCenter, Utc) as Closeness
    FROM [CheckIns]
    WHERE Utc < @DateCenter 
    ORDER BY Utc DESC
) AS temp
ORDER BY Closeness
```